# Checking that a linear vector bundle on $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is trivial

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Consider $\mathbb{RP}^n$ with standard charts $(\mathcal{U}_i,\varphi_i)_{i=1}^{n}$ and the linear vector bundle $E_d$ constructed from the transition maps
$$f_{jk}([x])= \left(\frac{x_k}{x_j}\right)^d \in GL(1,\mathbb{R}),\qquad [x]\in \mathcal{U}_j\cap \mathcal{U}_k$$
In other words, we set 
\begin{align*}E_d&:=\left[\bigsqcup_{j=1}^{n}\left(\left\{j\right\}\times \mathcal{U}_j\times \mathbb{R}\right)\right]/\sim\\ 
(j,p,g_j)\sim (k,p,g_k)&\iff g_j=f_{jk}(p)g_k,\; p\in \mathcal{U}_j\cap 
\mathcal{U}_k\\ 
&\pi([(j,p,g_j)]_{\sim})=p
\end{align*}
I need to prove that if $d$ is even, then $E_d$ is trivial, by proving that there exists a smooth global section vanishing nowhere. I do not understand why this is true only if $d$ is even. Intuitively, it is because $\left(\frac{x_k}{x_j}\right)^d$ is always positive only if $d$ is even, so it has to do with connectedness.

> But still, if I define the section  $$\sigma([x])=\left[
>  (i([x]),[x],1)\right]_{\sim}=\left\{\left(j,[x],\left(\frac{x_j}{x_{i([x])}}\right)^d\right):[x]\in
>  \mathcal{U}_j\cap \mathcal{U}_{i([x])}\right\}\in \pi^{-1}([x])\subset
>  E_d$$ Where $i:\mathbb{RP}^n\to \left\{1,\dots,n\right\}$ is any
>    function such that $[x]\in \mathcal{U}_{i([x])}$ for all $[x]$.
>    Clearly $\sigma$ vanishes nowhere, even if $d$ is odd, is everywhere
>   defined, and is smooth because the function $[x]\mapsto 1$ is smooth.

EDIT: As noted, $\sigma$ is not smooth globally but only in the level sets of the function $i:[x]\mapsto i([x])$. But this seems to be the case regardless of whether $d$ is odd or even, so I have no idea how to construct a smooth non-vanishing section when $d$ is even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you choose a function $i$, you can only conclude that $\sigma$ is smooth on open sets on which $i$ is constant. It is not continuous globally:

Fix $[x_0]$, let $j \neq i([x_0])$ and pick $[x_1]\in \mathcal{U}_{i([x_0])}\cap \mathcal{U}_j$ with $f_{i([x_1])j}([x])=-1$. Then $\sigma([x_1])=[i([x_1]),[x_1],1]=[j,[x_1],-1]$. Next let $[x_2]\in\mathcal{U}_j$ with $i([x_2])=j$, then $\sigma([x_2])=[j,[x_2],1]$. Connect $[x_1]$ and $[x_2]$ with a curve $c\subset \mathcal{U}_j$. Then $\sigma(c(t))=0$ for some $t$ by the intermediate value theorem, which is a contradiction.

---

*Edit:* Here is how you can define a global, nowhere vanishing section, if $d$ is even: View  $\mathbb{R}P^n$ as quotient of $S^{n}$. Then if $d$ is even,  the functions
$$
a_k:S^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x=(x_0,\dots,x_n)\mapsto x_k^d
$$
descend to functions $\bar a_k\colon \mathbb{R}P^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and we can define for $0\le k \le n$:
$$
\sigma_k([x])=[k,[x],\bar a_k([x])]\quad \text{for } [x]\in \mathcal{U}_k=\{x_k\neq 0\}.
$$
Clearly each $\sigma_k$ is smooth and nonvanishing. I claim that all sections glue together to a global section $\sigma$. Take $j,k$ and $[x]\in \mathcal{U}_j\cap \mathcal{U}_k$. Then
$$
\sigma_j([x])=[j,[x],\bar a_j([x])]=[k,[x],f_{jk}([x])\bar a_j([x])], \quad \text{ and } \quad \sigma_k([x])=[k,[x],\bar a_k([x])].
$$
But $f_{jk}([x])\bar a_j([x])=(x_k/x_j)^d\cdot x_j^d = x_k^d = \bar a_k([x])$, hence $\sigma_j([x])  = \sigma_k([x])$ and we are done.

Comment: 1) Is it not smooth because the function $[x]\mapsto i([x])$ is not continuous when I consider the codomain as $\mathbb{R}$? But then I don't see how there can even exist a smooth function from $\mathbb{RP}^n\to E_d$, since $i([x])\in \left\{1,\dots,n\right\}$ must always take at least 2 different values for the map to be globally defined and $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is connected. 2) $f_{i([x_1])j}([x])=-1$ is only possible if $d$ is odd. So if $d$ is even then is the map globally smooth? I don't see what changes in that case (aside from this argument not working anymore).

Comment: 1) No need to change the codomain: If $i$ was continuous, then its image would be connected in $\mathbb{Z}$, hence it would be constant. 2) Forget about $i$. Define $\sigma_j:\mathcal{U}_j\rightarrow E_d$ by $[x]\mapsto [j,[x],1]$. This is obviously a smooth, nonvanishing section and the question is, whether these local sections $\sigma_j$ glue together. For this you have to show $\sigma_j([x])= \sigma_k([x])$ whenever $[x]\in \mathcal{U}_j\cap \mathcal{U}_k$. And this *does* work, if $d$ is even.

Comment: I don't understand. $\sigma_{j}([x])=\left\{\left(i,[x],f_{ij}([x])\right):[x]\in \mathcal{U}_i\cap \mathcal{U}_j\right\}$, $\sigma_{k}([x])=\left\{\left(i,[x],f_{ik}([x])\right):[x]\in \mathcal{U}_i\cap \mathcal{U}_k\right\}$ Now , if $[x]\in \mathcal{U}_j\cap \mathcal{U}_k$; we have $[x]\in \mathcal{U}_i\cap \mathcal{U}_j$ if and only if $[x]\in \mathcal{U}_i\cap \mathcal{U}_k$. In these two sets two elements can be equal only if the index (first element of the triple) is equal. But $(i,[x],f_{ij}([x]))\in \sigma_j([x])\neq (i,[x],f_{ik}([x]))\in \sigma_k([x])$, in general,unless $j=k$

Comment: Basically what I get is $\sigma_j([x])=\sigma_k([x])\iff \left(\frac{x_i}{x_j}\right)^d=\left(\frac{x_i}{x_k}\right)^d$ for all $i$ such that $[x]\in \mathcal{U}_i\cap \mathcal{U}_j\cap \mathcal{U}_k$.

Comment: I agree, that this does not work. I still think that it is best to define local sections $\sigma_j$ on each affine set and try to patch them together. Let me think about how we can adjust the definition.

Comment: Adjusting the definition of $\sigma_j$ gives the desired section, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, you were really helpful!